# How to make DurableSubscriber always exist (JMS, Java)

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I'm using activeMQ and I want to know if we can make a DurableSubscriber alway exist. Let me explain myself.

I order to receive my topics, the DurableSubscriber first needs to be run at least once. It need to exist. It can be active or inactive but if it doesn't exist then all topics sent before the first run are lost.

If my subscriber is inactive my message are indeed saved and if I reactivate my subscriber before the delay of my messages it receives them correctly. But I still need to run my topic receiver once first in order to open the connection.

So is there a way to prevent this ? "Like saying to the sender "hey guy don't worry their is a subscriber but he doesn't exist yet, so wait for him" or making the subscriber always exist.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok actually it was an error of mine. I'll answer my own question if someone else does the same error.

In activemq.xml in the broker part :

```
 <broker useJmx="true"  xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}" offlineDurableSubscriberTimeout="30000" offlineDurableSubscriberTaskSchedule="15000">
```

As you can all see I wrongly put `offlineDurableSubscriberTimeout="3000000" offlineDurableSubscriberTaskSchedule="15000"`

This actually closes my subscriber every 3000 secondes.

So yes there is a way to make the durablesubscriber alway exist. Just need to avoid `offlineDurableSubscriberTimeout="X"` Until the server restarts the subscriber will live.